# Why is the result of "SELECT ISNULL(LEFT(NULL, 8), '1234567890')" returned as '1' instead of '1234567890'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT ISNULL(LEFT(NULL, 8), '1234567890')
```

The result I got is '1' instead of '1234567890'. What am I missing?

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Probably some implicit typecasting to `varchar(1)` or `char(1)`

Comment: Use coalesce instead, it will return values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one difference between ISNULL and COALESCE is that ISNULL limits the length of parameters to that of first whereas COALESCE won't. try the following to know the difference

```
DECLARE @i AS VARCHAR(4) = NULL, 
        @j AS VARCHAR(6) = 'abcdefg' 

SELECT ISNULL(@i, @j)
SELECT COALESCE (@i, @j)
```

Answer (score 1):

To limit the length of the result to 8 characters you need

```
SELECT ISNULL(cast(NULL as varchar(8)), '1234567890') ;
```

datatype of ISNULL result is inferred using the first argument.